# UISegmentedControl always appears dim

Tags: ios, user-interface, ios7, uisegmentedcontrol

No matter what settings I try, I cannot get UISegmentedControl to render with the tintColor I set.  I took a few screenshots, and it seems whatever color I set, the rendered result is 20% darker (i.e. UIColor whiteColor ends up R:204,G:204,B:204)

I've tried every combination of the settings below, and nothing seems to change the fact it always looks darker.  However, inspection of the tintAdjustmentMode at all stages before/after setting the values, appear, etc. comes out as UITintAdjustmentModeNormal.  I can make the background color of the text render at full brightness, but the frame and selected index fill is always at 80% brightness.  Oddly, this doesn't happen in the 7.1 Simulator, but it does happen on my iPhone 5 with 7.1.1.

Has anyone had similar problems?  I've read many other threads about controls *not* dimming, or people wanting to set different colors for different parts of the control, but couldn't find any about tintColors that won't show at full brightness.

Various settings I've tried individually and together:

```
UIColor *tintColorToSet = [UIColor colorWithRed:0/255.0f green:241/255.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f];
NSMutableDictionary *textAttributes = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
       tintColorToSet, NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
       [UIColor clearColor], NSBackgroundColorAttributeName,
       [UIFont fontWithName:@"NesController" size:18.0f], NSFontAttributeName, nil];
[_lengthBar setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[textAttributes setValue:[UIColor blackColor] forKey:NSForegroundColorAttributeName];
[_lengthBar setTitleTextAttributes:textAttributes forState:UIControlStateSelected];
_lengthBar.tintColor = tintColorToSet;
_lengthBar.alpha = 1.0f;
_lengthBar.tintAdjustmentMode = UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal;
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "but it does happen on my iPhone 5 with 7.1.1" Did you play with Settings > General > Accessibility in some way? Some settings here can alter your colors quite significantly.

Comment: I had turned on various options before (button shapes, text size, etc.) when they first came out, but now all of the settings are off.  I've compared with an iPad 3 on the same OS, and the same settings are producing different results... the iPad is showing the UISegmentedControl with the correct tint, like the simulator.  There must be something specific to the phone I'm missing.